# Nodejs hana-client connection pool example

Tags: node.js, hana

Can someone share the sample code in nodejs for connection pool using hana-client lib module,I am trying to resuse the same in multiple services in a rest api based app
Thanks
Arun

Comment: How about SAP's [official documents](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.7/en-US/e252ff9b2cb44dd9925901e39025ce77.html) on this?

Comment: I went through this, but whenever i create a client and call the connect with pooling true and the mxaPool parameter set to 10, it only opens up one connection for all the client.exc(),even if i call the same from multiple routes from node express app.Reference used https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.7/en-US/4fe9978ebac44f35b9369ef5a4a26f4c.html

Comment: But this is exactly what pooling is intended for. It will open new connection only when theres no more available connections in the pool.

Comment: I mean, its not adding any new connections other than the one opened up at connect method.I can see the queries are just queued up and getting executed sequently through the same connection.

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: If anybody still can't make it work I have posted my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75231752/4587136